# Different behaviour debug vs release(crash) on dll which used by java application

Tags: java, dll

I am using VS2012 and build four dlls which are used by my java application. The Debug version of those 4 dlls work fine and release version crash the java application. I got the following errors:

**First-chance exception at 0x6DEC3D05 (jvm.dll) in dbip.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x012C0980.
'dbip.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN encountered**

The following are my example code:
In my .h code, I have:

```
class _CABInterface : public CInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~CABInterface(void);

    static CABInterface* GetABInterface();
private:
    CABInterface(void);
    static CABInterface* m_pABInterface;
....
}
```

In my .cpp code:

```
CABInterface::CABInterface()
{//line A
    init();  //line B
}

CABInterface* CABInterface::GetABInterface()
{//line C
    if (m_pABInterface == NULL)
    {
        m_pABInterface = new CABInterface();
    }

    return m_pABInterface;
}
```

In my another .cpp file, I call GetABInterface() like:

```
CInterface* pJtagInterface = CABInterface::GetABInterface();  //line D
```

I set breakpoint on line D;
If I use debug version, from line D, go to line C, then go to line A, line B. Everything works as I expected;

However when I use release version, from line D, directly jump to line A. line c never get chance to execute;

The weird thing is after execute line B, it goes back to line A, the memory get messed up.

Anyone has any idea what I did wrong? I thought it is because my compile setting, but which one?
Thanks in advance!!!

Song

Answer (score 0):

The error regarding "Cannot find or open the PDB file" would suggest that it is still running in debug. PDB is not used in a Released version.

I'd verify that your project properties > Build > Output > Output Path is going to the correct locations for both the Debug and Release configuration.

You may also try a 'Clean' before building.

Also, debugs don't break on `{` (if this is how your code is formatted). It will only break on actual lines of code. If it is breaking on lines that do not contain actual code, it is running an older version of your code - from somewhere.